# Constructing a world ray from mouse coordinates

Tags: c++, raycasting

I've got the following c++ code. It produces a Ray from the mouse coordinates given. However the `z` coordinate is wrong, I expect it to be on the near plane of the view matrix, in this case `1` (from `position = { 0, 0, 1 }`). But it consistently returns `-1`

```
using namespace glm;
projection = perspective(radians(fov), (Floating)width / (Floating)height, 0.0001f, 10000.f);
vec3 center = position + direction;
view = lookAt(position, center, up);
vec2 mousePosition = { .x, .y };
vec2 normalisedCoords = {
 -1.0f + 2.0f * position.x / width,
  1.0f + -2.0f * position.y / height
};
//                                                      near z plane?
vec4 clipCoords = { normalisedCoords.x, normalisedCoords.y, -1, 1 };
mat4 invProjection = inverse(projection);
vec4 eyeCoords = invProjection * clipCoords;
mat4 invView = inverse(view);
vec4 rayWorld = invView * eyeCoords;
vec3 mouseRay = { rayWorld.x, rayWorld.y, rayWorld.z };
```

What modifications do I need to make to fix the `z` component? That or can someone suggest a better way of casting a world ray.

Answer (score 0):

`eyeCoords.w` component must be 1.0 before getting the `rayWorld`.
You need to divide the `eyeCoords` vector components by `eyeCoords.w`. That way you will get 1.0 for the w component and the mouse ray will show the correct value for z.

```
//                                                      near z plane?
vec4 clipCoords = { normalisedCoords.x, normalisedCoords.y, -1, 1 };
mat4 invProjection = inverse(projection);
vec4 eyeCoords = invProjection * clipCoords;
// vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
eyeCoords /= eyeCoords.w;  // divide each component by w component
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
mat4 invView = inverse(view);
vec4 rayWorld = invView * eyeCoords;
vec3 mouseRay = { rayWorld.x, rayWorld.y, rayWorld.z };
```

[More details about the perspective matrix can be found here](https://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html#perspective)